# Python keyboard module not capturing keystrokes when coverted to exe using pyinstaller

Tags: python, keyboard, exe, pyinstaller, keylogger

I wrote a keylogger function in Python 3.6 on Windows 10 using the (keyboard) module. It works perfectly when I run it on Python and captures all keystrokes. However, when I convert it to an exe using Pyinstaller (3.4) it does not capture anything no matter what or how many keys I press.

the code is:

```
import keyboard

def keylogger():
    keyboard.start_recording()
    sleep(20)
    gen = keyboard.stop_recording()
    logs = str(list(keyboard.get_typed_strings(gen)))
    return logs
```

Why doesn't it capture keystrokes when converted to an exe? Does it have to do with Windows access restrictions or maybe missing imports in Pyinstaller?

Comment: Where are you getting keyboard from - it is not a part of the standard library?

Comment: No. It's third party. https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard

Comment: Since that modules source code includes a .c file it will be being built to a binary, (likely a .dll), it is possible that pyInstaller needs to be told to include that and where to find it.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. The module description says "Pure Python, no C modules to be compiled". If this is not true how can I know what is the missing file.

Comment: try using the module **pynput** instead

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is to rerun your exe when you detect keyboard hook does not work:

```
keyboard.hook(self.__key_on)
keyboard.start_recording()
win32api.keybd_event(160, 0, win32con.KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
ev_list = keyboard.stop_recording()
if not ev_list:
    print("Couldn't set keyboard hooks. Trying once again...\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    os.system(dir_path + r"\programr.exe")
    sys.exit(1)
```